# I tried setting up pptpd server and nothing will go through

Tags: server, pptpd

I have tried for days to setup a pptpd server and followed the guide exactly. I was getting an error that the server wasn't responding from the client, but after port fowarding through the router, I got that to go away. Now, I get a message saying You were disconnected from the communication device.I have tried everything and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Please inform what guide are you following. Try to watch the logs and inform here about the lines you consider most important. The logs should be defined into the configuration file, and if aren't, then logs are disabled or it is logging to default file(s).